# Go CI does not recognize build file for gradle

Tags: gradle, continuous-integration, go-cd

I have setup GO CI pipeline for continuous integration in my project. I tried to add a project that is built using gradle. I tried a add gradle task for building my application. [image]

While executing build it shows that

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'build' not found in root project 'Gradlepipelinejob'.
```

I tried to add `defaultTasks 'clean', 'compile`' to the parent build.gradle file. But still the same error exists. Someone pls help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: Can you run the "build" task locally on your PC? If not, you probably need to apply the right plugins, like "java" or whatever language you're using.
Preferably edit the question to include your build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

I think 'build' should be in Command section, rather than  arguments.          Even after that if it doesn't works, try executing build commands in the agent terminal(or any command prompt).This will let you figure out whether the error is in server or agent.

Answer (score 0):

GO CI runs the command in the code checkout directory so please check if your gradle file is present or not in that directory